# How to loop and get the values from second array in sequence

Tags: php

This is the Array I want to loop Into Events Index and get all the context print out of it how can i do this

Here is the Array Code Which i am trying to loop

```
[1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => RPDNLNYO6U
            [active] => 
            [events] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => RPDNLNYO6U_1
                            [created_at] => 2023-02-06T10:55:42.501003Z
                            [visibility] => all
                            [text] => Hi
                            [author_id] => 170bdd03-a163-49e9-4295-11fae376ff0e
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => RPDNLNYO6U_2
                            [created_at] => 2023-02-06T10:55:44.102000Z
                            [visibility] => all
                           
                            [text] => I need help
                            [author_id] => 170bdd03-a163-49e9-4295-11fae376ff0e
                            
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => RPDNLNYO6U_3
                            [created_at] => 2023-02-06T11:06:11.002000Z
                            [visibility] => agents
                            [type] => system_message
                            [text] => Chat is idle due to 10 minutes of inactivity
                            [system_message_type] => routing.idle
                            [text_vars] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [duration] => 10
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => RPDNLNYO6U_4
                            [created_at] => 2023-02-06T11:11:14.002000Z
                            [visibility] => all
                            [type] => system_message
                            [text] => Chat archived due to 15 minutes of inactivity
                            [system_message_type] => routing.archived_inactive
                            [text_vars] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [duration] => 15
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

Comment: You can learn basic foreach and arrays to get started for this.

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this array?

Comment: yes i want to get all the text from the events array 
here is my Code im using 

foreach($obj_thread as $ky => $val){
        
  
        foreach($obj_thread as $ky=>$val){
            
            echo $val->events[$i]->text.'<br>';
            //echo "Hi + ".$j;
           
        }
        echo "<br>";
        
        $i++;
}

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a foreach loop in PHP to loop through the array and get all the context you need.

```
$array = [1 => (object) [
    'id' => 'RPDNLNYO6U',
    'active' => '',
    'events' => [
        (object) [
            'id' => 'RPDNLNYO6U_1',
            'created_at' => '2023-02-06T10:55:42.501003Z',
            'visibility' => 'all',
            'text' => 'Hi',
            'author_id' => '170bdd03-a163-49e9-4295-11fae376ff0e'
        ]
    ]
]];

foreach ($array as $object) {
    $id = $object->id;
    $active = $object->active;
    foreach ($object->events as $event) {
        $event_id = $event->id;
        $created_at = $event->created_at;
        $visibility = $event->visibility;
        $text = $event->text;
        $author_id = $event->author_id;
        echo "Event ID: $event_id, Created At: $created_at, Visibility: $visibility, Text: $text, Author ID: $author_id\n";
    }
}
```

This will loop through the outer array and print out all the context for each event.

Comment: foreach($obj_thread as $ky => $val){
        echo $val->id. '<br>';
        if($val->active==""){
            echo "Offline";
        }else if($val->active=="1"){
            echo "Online";
        }
        echo $val->active.'<br>';
        $My_date=strtotime($val->events[$i]->created_at);
        echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $My_date).'<br>';
        foreach($obj_thread as $ky=>$val){
            
            echo $val->events[$i]->text.'<br>';
            //echo "Hi + ".$j;
           
        }
        echo "<br>";
        
        $i++;
}

this is how i am loopin